# React GSAP css animation from right to left with transform

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transform, gsap

I am refactoring a project using functional components and React Hooks.

The original animation move the **BG** Component from right to left but for some reasons with exactly the same code my animation works the other way around ( from left to right ). I have to correct this behavior.

I have reproduced the case => https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-currying-63uy9w?file=/src/features/bg/Bg.js

This is the code that is not working as expected, in the **BG** component i have the *useEffect* to animate BG direction in the timeline with GSAP

```
  useEffect(() => {
    tl.addLabel("phase-3", 0.5).fromTo(
      boxRef.current,
      t3,
      {
        transformOrigin: "100% 0",
        transform: "scaleX(0) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"
      },
      {
        transform: "scaleX(1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"
        // ease: Elastic.easeOut
      },
      "phase-3"
    );
  });
```

So the question is, how can i animate the component from **right to left** and not from left to right as it is now? What am i doing wrong?